# Scrape website Data USING Symfony's DomCrawler Component

Tags: php, symfony

I need to scrape the number values that has "CR" on this website such as:

http://webapps.nyc.gov:8084/cics/f704/f403001i?BBL=1-00259-0071

Unfortunately, I cannot find a solution to this using the DomCrawler filter method

http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html

Any experienced Symfony users can help me? Or give me any advice

This is what I have using the xpath method:

```
 $crawler->filterXPath('//div/center/table/tbody/tr/td[contains(., 'CR')]')->text()
```

Update I managed to grab all the CR's using:

```
//td/font[contains(., 'CR')]
```

But what i need are the numbers

Thank you

Comment: SO is not a place for people to get developers to works for them for free. Post your code, what you've tried so far and what's the error you're getting. This can be easily done with only curl and regex.

Comment: I'm not familiar or have any experience with xpath.  This is what I have using the xpath method

     $crawler->filterXPath('//div/center/table/tbody/tr/td[contains(., 'CR')]')->text();

Answer (score 2):

The crawler is similar to SimpleXML and jQuery. If you're not familiar with them, you'd have hard time figuring out how to get the content. You don't have to explicitly use `xpath` to get the content. You could do that with a `filter` (similar to jQuery's, i.e. `filter('body > .my_class')`

```
$url = '...';

$crawler = new Crawler(file_get_contents($url));

$crawler->filterXPath("//td/font[contains(., ' CR')]")->each(function(Crawler $node, $i){
    $string = filter_var($node->parents()->first()->text(), FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
    $string = str_replace('CR', ' CR', $string);
    var_dump($string);
});
```